# Radii and curvatures

Tags: geometry

In this image, consider the 3 arcs $AB, BC, \text{and} CD$ with the given radii of curvature. What is given is that arcs $AB$ and $CD$ are aligned with arc $BC$ at points B and C i.e.  making 180 degrees.

[image]

My question is about the radius $R_3$ of arc $BC$. I know that $R_1$ should be perpendicular to the tangent to arc $AB$ at B and because it is algined with arc $BC$ then it should be perpendicular to tangent to arc $BC$ at B. but $R_3$ is also perpendicular to the tangent at B, so should $R_3$ be aligned with radius $R_1$?

Comment: Yes, so the centres of arcs $AB$ and $BC$, and point $B$ are on the same line.

Comment: @peterwhy, here is my problem, don't forget that it is aligned as well with arc $DC$. so the center should be aligned with $R_2$ as well, which seems impossible for me

Comment: So the centre of arc $BC$ would be where segments $R_1$ and $R_2$ (or their extensions) intersect.